# forEach returns undefined - How to return an array instead?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given below is the code in which I tried to modify an array using arrow function but while running, it returns a value of undefined as the output can someone give suggestions please

```js
var modifyArray = (nums) => {
     return nums.forEach(function (element) {
          (element % 2 == 0) ? element *= 2 : element *= 3;
     })
}
console.log(modifyArray([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Comment: `forEach` method doesn't return any particular value, that is it will return `undefined`. You can try to use `Array.prototype.map` instead.
```
return nums.map(function (element) {
          (element % 2 == 0) ? element *= 2 : element *= 3;
     })

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.forEach` returns undefined. You probably want to `.map` to a new array and return that:

```
 return nums.map(function (element) {
      return element * ((element % 2 == 0) ? 2 : 3);
 });
```

For sure you also have to return the statement inside of the inner function, otherwise that evaluates to undefined too.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't return anything - use `map` instead:

```js
var modifyArray = nums => nums.map(element => element % 2 == 0 ? element *= 2 : element *= 3)
console.log(modifyArray([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Also note that inside of the function passed to `forEach` you weren't returning anything - with ES5 `function` you need to explicitly `return` - not required with ES6 `=>`.

Comment: I get your point but even if he explicitly return from inside the callback method, it still would have got nothing since forEach expects a method that returns void

Answer (score 0):

See the answers above.

There is a workaround if you still want to use `forEach`

```
let result = []
var modifyArray = (nums) => {
     nums.forEach(function (element) {
          result.push((element % 2 == 0) ? element *= 2 : element *= 3);
     })
    return result;

}
modifyArray([1,2,3,4,5])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using for loops?

```
var modifyArray = (nums) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        let element = nums[i];
        // console.log(element + ' - ' + element % 2 );
        nums[i] = (element % 2 == 0) ? element *= 2 : element *= 3;
    }
    return nums;
}

console.log(modifyArray([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

For each returns undefined as it doesn't return anything but you can use forEach for doing the same thing by pushing your data into an array. Notice I did not change your approach but just extended it

```js
var modifyArray = (nums) => {
  var somearray = []
  nums.forEach((element) => somearray.push((element % 2 == 0) ? element *= 2 : element *= 3));
  return somearray;
}
console.log(modifyArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Use `array.push` to push data to an array. If you want to use the map method you can also use that like

```js
var modifyArray = (nums) => {
     return nums.map((element) => { return (element % 2 == 0) ? element *= 2 : element *= 3 });
}
console.log(modifyArray([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Wanna use for loops? Then you can also try this approach. It's the same as the forEach loop

```js
var modifyArray = (nums) => {
  var somearray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    somearray.push((nums[i] % 2 == 0) ? nums[i] *= 2 : nums[i] *= 3)
  }
  return somearray;
}

console.log(modifyArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```